# Which of the C-family languages have a preprocessor?

Tags: preprocessor, compatibility, c-preprocessor

Among the **C**-syntax family of languages (**C**, C++, Java, C#, ObjC, JS, AS, ...), which have a preprocessor compatible (to whatever extent) with the **C** preprocessor?

Comment: As an added note, it is common for Fortran and some assembly code to also make use of the C preprocessor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Objective C is a superset of the C language and was initially implemented as an additional preprocessor to C code. It is fully compatible with C preprocessor.

None of the others you name have preprocessors compatible with the C spec. Keep in mind that preprocessors are an assembler/compiler-specific thing in many cases, and the functionality you are looking for may or may not be found in different, proprietary IDEs/Compilers.

Of course, C++ is 100% (more or less) compatible as well.

Answer (score 0):

C++ and objective-C both use the C preprocessor, none of the others do.

You can always add a macro processor or template language to any build process if you need it.

Answer (score 0):

Java and JS have no preprocessor (JS understandably, really, since you can run strings as code in-language). Not sure about AS, but C, C++, and ObjC all have a C-grade preprocessor.

C# does have a preprocessor, but I've never used it, and thus cannot talk about it's use.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ed8yd1ha(VS10.0).aspx

The Boost preprocessor library is awesum.